# Syncing sound with CSS animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation, audio, howler.js

I wrote simple code to sync sound with CSS animation
[I use Howler JS library for the sound.]

Here's the [code](https://codepen.io/alienmon/pen/vyQoww?editors=0110)

***CSS***:

```
body{
  padding:100px;
}
#p1{
  -webkit-animation:spinL 1.2s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spinL 1.2s linear infinite;
    animation:spinL 1.2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spinL 
{ 
  /* 0% to 25% : 15 degree to 0 degree*/
  100% { -webkit-transform: translate(300px); transform:translate(300px); }
}
```

***JS:***

```
var sound = new Howl({
  src: ['https://www.dropbox.com/s/p9btintz9ot03id/22744__franciscopadilla__41-low-floor-tom.wav?raw=1']});

var p1Sound=document.getElementById("p1");

p1Sound.addEventListener("animationiteration",function(e){
  sound.play(); //play right when iteration begins
  setTimeout(function(){sound.play();}, 400);  //play after 0.4s
  setTimeout(function(){sound.play();}, 800); //play after 0.8s 
},false);
```

I bind eventlistener to element p1. The event is : iteration of animation.
The period of 1 animation iteration is 1.2s,

Everytime the iteration happens: 
I play sound at 
0s(beginning & at the same time end of animation), 
0.4s(1/3 way) and 
0.8s (2/3 way). (Using timeout to adjust the time)

The sound is supposed to play at constant interval 0.4 s.
HOWEVER, at the beginning(first few seconds), the sound doesn't play like it is supposed to do, rather it plays arbitrarily. It needs few seconds, until it play with regular interval as intended.
**Why is that so? and how to fix this?**

Second, if I open the link using my phone instead of PC, it DOES NOT play sound AT ALL. Please help why?
[I tried simple code to just play a sound using howler JS in phone, and it works, so I suppose the problem is not in the howler JS]

Comment: In what browser do you test in? Not all browsers support Web Audio API and if regular audio element is used instead the delay comes from buffering and decoding.

Comment: @K3N I tested in Chrome both in PC and phone. The sound plays in my PC, but not in my phone. In my PC, even though it plays, the first few seconds, it doesn't play regularly.

Comment: (1) You need to verify that the sound is already loaded and ready to play. If you have a lot of sounds, use Howler's sound sprites, because there are limits on the number of sounds that can be loaded at once and ready to play.

Comment: (2) You can attach sounds to the animation elements in the document and assign eventhandlers to the onend onplay events.